# Is it true that $\lim_{ x\to a}(f(x)/g(x)) = f(a)/g(a)$ without the assumption $g(a)\ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Test prep problem:

> If f and g are continuous functions, then $\lim_{ x\to a}(f(x)/g(x)) = f(a)/g(a)$.  State whether this is True or False. Provide proof or a counterexample.

While this is the limit law, it does not state while $g(a) \ne 0$.

With this left out is this statement true or false?

Comment: It's false since if $g(a)=0$, $\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need $g(a) \neq 0$.  Then there is a neighborhood of $a$ where $g(x) \neq 0$ (prove that).  Then you can do an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof with the usual technique of splitting the allowable error between $f$ and $g$.